# Issue accessing root URL in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

I had an API Gateway instance and all was working well until I added a custom domain with some API Mappings.

I had to re-factor my routes a little, but ended up with a single `/{proxy+}` route which works for `api.mydomain.com/account/profile` but doesn't for the root path of  `api.mydomain.com/account`.

I have tried adding the `$default` route to API Gateway and tried various other routes to try to catch this `/` URL but all seems to result in a `Not Found` error at API Gateway level, the Lambda doesn't even spin up.

I've attached a couple of images of my current set up in API Gateway.

What am I doing wrong? If there is anything else you need to see, let me know and I will update the question with the information.

[image]

[image]

In case it makes a difference, I am using API Gateway V2

Answer (score 0):

So it was just the fact of re-adding the `$default` route. When I previously attempted this, I must have just missed adding the integration to it or something. All works now.